# Apply LSH approxNearestNeighbors on all rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, lsh

I am trying to apply BucketedRandomProjectionLSH's function `model.approxNearestNeighbors(df, key, n)` on all the rows of a dataframe in order to approx-find the top n most similar items for every item. My dataframe has 1 million rows.

My problem is that I have to find a way to compute it within a reasonable time (no more than 2 hrs). I've read about that function `approxSimilarityJoin(df, df, threshold)` but the function takes way too long and doesn't return the right number of rows : if my dataframe has 100.000 rows, and I set a threshold VERY high/permissive I get something like not even 10% of the number of rows returned.

So, I'm thinking about using `approxNearestNeighbors` on all rows so that the computation time is almost linear.

How do you apply that function to every row of a dataframe ? I can't use a UDF since I need the model + a dataframe as inputs.

Do you have any suggestions ?